# DTC issues using Oracle and .NET 4 - RM_COMMIT_DELIVERY_FAILED_DUE_TO_CONNECTION_DOWN

Tags: c#, oracle, wcf, msdtc

First a little intro to our setup:

- WCF based app with EF 4 context injected using Unity (no singleton)
- Oracle running on a seperate physical machine
- NServiceBus handling messages that access Oracle through the same context as above

The problem we are experiencing, only on our UAT environment, is that we cannot send multiple messages without receiving distributed transaction locks on DTC. The DTC trace tells us this:

```
1. TRANSACTION_COMMITTED
2. RM_ISSUED_COMMIT
3. RM_ISSUED_COMMIT
4. RM_ACKNOWLEDGED_COMMIT    
5. RM_COMMIT_DELIVERY_FAILED_DUE_TO_CONNECTION_DOWN
```

Any bright ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem lies within our client app WCF configuration.

Deep down in our framework we are setting TransactionFlow = true which tries to setup a transaction scope starting from the client. If we run our request and fire of a NServiceBus message we loose the link with our client and cannot commit the transaction.

So **TransactionFlow = false** in app.config saved us.

Comment: Another issue we encountered with Devart is that if your Oracle user password is bound to expire you will encounter the same behaviour as described above. The Oracle server responds to the initial query with the result that you're password is going to expire. On this event the Devart driver closes the connection and the real answer will never arrive due to a closed connection and finally result in the DTC holding the locks because it receives no aknowledge.